# Расширения подключаемых файлов (require)

Tags: php, база-данных, безопасность, require

У меня есть куски html, вывод которых зависит от определенных условий, имеют расширение des (file.des) - никакого php-кода в них нет.

Есть еще файл dbase.inc - в нем код и данные подключения к бд. Если (например!) набрать в строке браузера http://site/dbase.inc, то выведется файл с именем и паролем...

Вопрос: Обязательно нужно у подключаемых файлов с php-кодом использовать расширение php ?

Еще гипотетический баг: Есть файл allmyfinc.inc. Если допущена ошибка в коде этого файла и сообщение о ней покажется, то в нем будет написано, что ошибка в такой-то строке в файле allmyfinc.inc. И набрав http://site/allmyfinc.inc в браузере, почти весь код сайта станет доступен.

---

О хранении данных для подключения к бд выше корня сайта я знаю. Но еще не реализовал. Пока что вопрос о расширении.

Comment: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .inc`

Comment: У тебя талант задавать вопросы, смысла которых не понимает никто. В чем проблема сделать файлу расширение .рнр?

Comment: @Ипатьев Лютый транслит в имени + странные вопросы. Даже ачивка "Бродяга" уже в копилке. Человек привык спрашивать и не привык думать.

Comment: что кому не понятно? Вопрос: Обязательно нужно у подключаемых файлов с php-кодом использовать расширение php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расширения файлов обрабатываемых php указываются явно в файле конфигурации веб-сервера. Как правило inc там нет, ограничиваются php, phtml. Но можно и дополнить, естественно. Поэтому все критичные к просмотру подключаемые файлы должны иметь расширение php. Альтернатива - через .htaccess можно запретить их вызов, сервер будет отдавать 403 ошибку при попытке доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший тон - вынести все php файлы, кроме точек входа (index.php) за пределы публичной директории, т.е. структура может быть примерно следующая:

```
/libary/
--db/
----config.inc
/controllers/
--controller.php
/public_html/
--index.php
```

Web сервер должен быть настроен на директорию public_html. В таком случае у пользователя не будет возможности с помощью браузера получить содержимое того же конфига, который просто не может быть отправлен веб-сервером, однако может быть подлючен с помощью include.

Comment: ну всё выносить не нужно. Остальное понял.